# React native useContext returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I can't access the data passed by createContext using useContext hook in the functional component in react native :
context.js is as

```
import React , {createContext,useState}  from 'react';
 export const Style1 = React.createContext();
export  default StyleContextProvider = (props) => {
const [myValue,setValue] = useState([{one: 1},{two : 2}]);
console.log("value from context : " + myValue);
    return ( 
        <Style1.Provider value={[myValue,setValue]}>
          {props.children}
        </Style1.Provider>
     );
}
```

and App.js is as

```
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from './routes/sidebar';
import StyleContextProvider from './routes/context';
export default function App(props) {
  return (
        <StyleContextProvider>
          <Sidebar ></Sidebar>
        </StyleContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Sidebar.js is as

```
import React ,{useContext } from 'react';
import {  Text, View ,Button} from 'react-native';
import Style1 from '../routes/context';
const Sidebar = () =>{
 const value =  useContext(Style1);
 console.log("value from sidebar : " + value);  // value from sidebar : undefined

return (
    <View>
      <Practice></Practice>
    </View>
)
}
```

Practice.js

```
import  React  ,{useContext }from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import {View, StyleSheet,Text} from 'react-native';
import Style1 from '../routes/context';
const Practice = (props) => {
  const  Value =  useContext(Style1);
  console.log("value from practice : " + Value); // value from practice : undefined 
    return ( 
      <View >
        <Text>Value : {Value}</Text>
      </View>
     );
}
 export default Practice;
```

I'm getting undefined from the practice .js and sidebar.js , Any one with solution

Comment: Is App.js in same level as routes folder? What about the other files?

Comment: not that isn't in the same level

Comment: Strange because this `  ./routes/` indicates they are on same level. Can you add details showing your directory with locations of various files/folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your context you are setting the values as `value={[myValue,setValue]}`.

Which means in order to access them, you'll need to use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like:

```js
const [value, setValue] = React.useContext(Style1);
```

Another note, since `value` is an array of objects, you cannot directly render it. You'll either need to iterate using `map()` or access the value directly.

```
- <Text>Value : {Value}</Text>
+ <Text>Value : {value[0].one}</Text>
```

Here is a working sample based off of your snippets:

```js
const Style1 = React.createContext();
const StyleContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [myValue, setValue] = React.useState([{ one: 1 }, { two: 2 }]);
  console.log("value from context : ", myValue);
  return (
    <Style1.Provider value={[myValue, setValue]}>
      {props.children}
    </Style1.Provider>
  );
};

const View = (props) => <div>{props.children}</div>;
const Text = (props) => <span>{props.children}</span>;

const Practice = (props) => {
  const [value] = React.useContext(Style1);
  console.log("value from practice : ", value); // value from practice : undefined
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Value : {value[0].one}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [value] = React.useContext(Style1);
  console.log("value from sidebar : ", value); // value from sidebar : undefined

  return (
    <View>
      <Practice></Practice>
    </View>
  );
};

function App(props) {
  return (
    <StyleContextProvider>
      <Sidebar></Sidebar>
    </StyleContextProvider>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

> P.S: I do not know how to render React Native stuff using the StackOverflow snippet widget, hence took the liberty to create `Text` and `View` components.